# REST output with code igniter doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, i have made a simple rest to my web app like this:

```
    $request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));

            switch ($method) {
                case 'PUT':
                 ...
                 ...

                case 'GET':
                   $this->output
                     **->set_header("Content-Type: application/json**; charset=utf-8")
                     ->set_output(json_encode($arr));
                    break;

            }
```

And the output header from browser prints the same "text/html" content-type.

What is wrong?

Comment: $method isn't defined?  headers were already sent? No way to tell, since you haven't provided enough code.

Comment: Sorry , $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; ( was implicit )

Comment: If i use header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")        the PHP way , than "headers were already sent" message came in, so i have to use the CI way like above.

Comment: in CI3-dev you can use $this->input->method()

Comment: i cannot understand yet, can you give something more. Do you mean $method = $this->input->method()  ???

Comment: i understand, but input don't  have  methods put and delete.   I need a restful implementation. Under the hood Ci makes the same thing